# Why are the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$ equal to the monotone class generated by the open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mathcal{M}$ denote the monotone class generated by all open intervals $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is also the $\sigma$-field generated by the open intervals, the monotone class theorem implies that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{M}$.

The Borel $\sigma$-field contains all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and so the above implies that $\mathcal{M}$ must as well. However, I don't understand why this follows from the definition of $\mathcal{M}$. For example, how can I write $(0,1) \cup (1,2)$ as the countable union of an increasing sequence of open intervals?

Edit: to be clear, I understand that the fact that $\mathcal{M}$ is closed under countable monotone intersections and unions does not imply that all $A \in \mathcal{M}$ can be written as countable monotone intersection or union, but I'm still not really clear about how sets like the one above can arise in the monotone class.

To put this another way, how can I prove that $(0,1) \cup (1,2) \in \mathcal{M}$ without using the monotone class theorem?

Edit: the open intervals are not an algebra, e.g. they are not closed under finite unions, so I think the monotone class theorem isn't used correctly here.

Answer (score 1):

You are very right to be confused - the result **as stated in wikipedia** is incorrect. This is *almost* noticed at the talk page there, and see [here](http://stat.math.uregina.ca/%7Ekozdron/Teaching/Regina/451Fall13/Handouts/451lecture07.pdf) for a correct statement of the theorem.

The issue is that we need to also include the ability to form **finite set differences** in order to get things like $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$. To see this, note the following:

> Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be the class of all **convex** subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, that is, all $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that whenever $a,b\in A$ with $a<b$ we have $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathfrak{C}$ contains every open interval, is closed under countable increasing unions, and is closed under countable decreasing intersections.

At a glance, I believe that what happened is this: the term "monotone class" is generally used to refer to a class of sets closed under countable increasing unions and countable decreasing intersections. However, at least one source (see the talk page) uses "monotone class" to refer to [Dynkin systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system). The article then mixes this up.

Finally, to wrap things up, suppose $\mathfrak{D}$ is a Dynkin system containing each of the open intervals. For each $\epsilon<1$ we have $$X_\epsilon:=(0,2)\setminus (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)\in \mathfrak{D}.$$ Now consider the countable increasing union $$Y=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_{1\over n}.$$ This $Y$ is again in $\mathfrak{D}$, and is exactly $(0,1)\cup (1,2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like both the Wikipedia page on the [monotone class theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Monotone_class_theorem_for_sets) and the book I'm using [Real Analysis for Graduate Students](http://bass.math.uconn.edu/v42.pdf) (page 14) assume that the set of generators is an Algebra for the MCT: i.e. it needs to be closed under complements, and under finite unions and intersections.

Comment: I realized that the open intervals do not form an algebra: they're not closed under finite unions. Does this resolve the issue, or are you saying that the assumption of an algebra is also incorrect?

Comment: In any case, you're saying that $\mathfrak{C}$ is a monotone class which clearly doesn't contain $(0,1) \cup (1,2)$. Thank you for that great example. Is the MCT assuming an algebra equivalent to the MCT assuming a Dynkin system? How should I think about the difference between an algebra and a dynkin system?

Comment: was wondering if you got a chance to think about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the definition  of $\mathcal M$. $\mathcal M$ is the smallest class of sets closed under increasing and decreasing unions and containing all open intervals. This does not mean that every set in it is  a countable increasing union of open intervals. In fact your set cannot be written in this form.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I understand this. To put this another way: how would you prove directly that $(0,1) \cup (1,2) \in \mathcal{M}$ without using the monotone class theorem?

Comment: @TheProofIsTrivium You may require infinitely many operations of taking increasing unions and decreasing intersectioins to arrive at $(0,1) \cup (1,2)$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Actually I believe that the result in the OP is incorrect (wikipedia gets it wrong): every set in the class as defined there is in fact convex.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You are right.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Am I correct that I was mis-applying the monotone class theorem here, since the open intervals are not an algebra? I can't understand if Noah was saying that the assumption of an algebra in the MCT (which is what's written in Wikipedia) is incorrect or not.